# Error: Birthday.search is not a function (AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, rest, web-applications

I'm coding a web app in html, AngularJS and REST (rest modified for my teachers).
My program should load participants in a select in the openning. But show i.e {{participants.name}} and not {{Jhon}}

The problem is at the moment that would load method "search".

Error:

> "Error: Birthday.search is not a function
>   $scope.updateList@localhost:9000/birthday.js:26:1
>   @localhost:9000/birthday.js:31:5
>   e@localhost:9000/node_modules/angular/angular.min.js:36:313
>   Fe/this.$get

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es" data-ng-app="birthdayApp">
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilo.css">
    <script src="birthday.js"></script>
</head>
[...]
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid" data-ng-controller="BirthdayControllers as birthday">
[...]
    <select size="2" class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12">
        <option data-ng-repeat="participant in participants | filter:filter"> {{participant.name}} </option>
    </select>
[...]
```

The head its ok?

AngularJS

```
'use strict';
var app = angular.module("birthdayApp", [])

app.factory('Birthday', function($http) {
    return function(errorHandler) {
        this.search = function(callback, errorHandler) {
            $http.get('/participants').success(callback).catch(errorHandler);
        }
    }
});

/* Controllers */
app.controller("BirthdayControllers", function($scope, Birthday) {
    $scope.participants = null;

    var errorHandler = function(error) {
        $scope.notificarError(error.data);
    };

    $scope.updateList = function() {
    Birthday.search(function(data) { //here stop, here the problem!
            $scope.participants = data;
        }, errorHandler);
    }

    $scope.updateList();
[...]

});
```

Answer (score 1):

My factories look different. Here's how I do mine:

```
app.factory('Birthday', function ($http) {    
  return {
    search: function() {
      return $http.get('/participants');
    }
  };
});
```

Controller would look like this:

```
Birthday.search().success(function(data) {
  $scope.participants = data;
}).error(function(data, status, headers, config)  {
  //handle the error
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to return a factory object from the function not another function.
So modify your code like this:

```
app.factory('Birthday', function($http) {
return {
    search: function() {
        return $http.get('/participants');
    }
};
});
```

It's better to handle the callbacks in the controller, so call the factory method like this:

```
Birthday.search().success(function(data) {
        $scope.participants = data;
    }).catch(function(error) {
        $scope.notificarError(error.data);
    });
```